# Jets.js error: Uncaught Error: Error! Could not find searchTag element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use Jets.js for in page search of a series of unordered lists, but I keep getting this error with a single ul:

```
jets.js:23 Uncaught Error: Error! Could not find searchTag element
(anonymous function) @ jets.js:23
Jets @ jets.js:17
(anonymous function) @ index.html:34
```

The JavaScript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jets/0.11.0/jets.js"></script>
    <script>
        var jets = new Jets({
          searchTag: '#jetsSearch',
          contentTag: '.jetsContent',
          searchSelector: '*OR'
        });
    </script>
```

and the HTML is:

```
                            <input type="search" id="jetsSearch">
                            <ul class="jetsContent">
                                <li>
                                    <span class="icon major style1 fa-code"></span>
                                    <h3>Ipsum consequat</h3>
                                    <p>Sed lorem amet ipsum dolor et amet nullam consequat a feugiat consequat tempus veroeros sed consequat.</p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="icon major style3 fa-copy"></span>
                                    <h3>Amed sed feugiat</h3>
                                    <p>Sed lorem amet ipsum dolor et amet nullam consequat a feugiat consequat tempus veroeros sed consequat.</p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="icon major style5 fa-diamond"></span>
                                    <h3>Dolor nullam</h3>
                                    <p>Sed lorem amet ipsum dolor et amet nullam consequat a feugiat consequat tempus veroeros sed consequat.</p>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

Comment: Did you try moving your scripts down to right above `</body>` ?

Comment: Wrap your `new Jets()` in an `onload` function.

Comment: Seems to be that you have placed JavaScript before `#jetsSearch` element so you have two options: or move `<script>` tag down, right before `</body>` or wrap inner content of `<script>` in `window.onload = function() { ...your script... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var pre = onload;
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre();

var jets = new Jets({
  searchTag: '#jetsSearch',
  contentTag: '.jetsContent',
  searchSelector: '*OR'
});

}
```

Comment: Yep. It needed an onload.